# Protecting Magento Images

Tags: magento

It is good that magneto offers watermarking of images so a watermarked image will appear as

```
http://www.yourwebsite.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/de684549e4151748e56ee0dd7902c19f/m/y/my-first-image.jpg
```

This is good. But if anyone removes the cache/1/image/de684549e4151748e56ee0dd7902c19f part of URL so that it becomes

```
http://www.yourwebsite.com/media/catalog/product/m/y/my-first-image.jpg
```

He can view the image and copy it. What is best way to cope up with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to do it.

Put an .htaccess file in `media/catalog/` folder in Magento with following code in it

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine on  
#Following line allows the actual images to be accessed by admin end directly  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.yourwebsite.com/.*$ [NC]  
#Following line allows the watermarked images to be accessed directly. Rule says that if URL does not contain cache  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/cache/) [NC]  
#This is the page where visitor will be redirected if tries to access images directly.  
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ http://www.yourwebsite.com/do-not-try-to-steal-images.html/ [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, create yourself your images with the watermark !!! Like that if the cache is deleted, the cache will recreate an image from the already watermarked image

Answer (score 0):

You can create an .htaccess file in the media/catalog folder with the following lines in it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*?/cache.*)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [F]
```

This will return a 403 to the user if they try to view the original file but let them see the images that are in the cache.

This breaks previewing the images in the admin as they display the original files and not a generated thumbnail.

Comment: Thank You Jasuten! I was able to do with slight modification that is posted as answer below.